# Rhapsody + Mac OS X

Tags: macos, music

I've been using the music service [Rhapsody](http://www.rhapsody.com) for over a month now, and I really like it on my iPhone.  Unfortunately, I spend most of my time in front of my computer, programming.  I'm kind of so-so on the web client for Rhapsody, and I particularly would like to be able to download songs to my Mac.  I don't have access to a (legally obtainable) copy of any version of Windows, so VirtualBox/Parallels/etc. is out.  Wine doesn't really work with the Windows Rhapsody client.  Has anyone else encountered and/or solved this problem?  Switching from Rhapsody to some other service isn't really an option either, since so far, at least, no other "all-you-can-eat" music service has an iPhone app with downloading allowed.

Comment: will someone who can create tags tag this one with Rhapsody?

Answer (score 1):

[Spotify](http://www.spotify.com) has all that, but I’m not sure if you can use it in your country. Have you tried it?

**UPDATE** I found out that you’re in the USA, and Spotify only works in a few European Countries… unless you’re a “Premium” user; the catch is that you need to create your account from within Europe. I.e.: if you are european and want to travel, you can “take your music with you”… if you’re not a free user. Otherwise you can only use Spotify for 14 days until you return to your country.  *sorry about that*.

Answer (score -1):

What about Napster? They have an iPhone and a web client and their pay scheme and service is similar to Rhapsody:

> Find your favorite music in Napster’s
>   catalog of 9 Million songs. Buy songs
>   on your phone, they will be sent to
>   your computer so you can transfer them
>   to your phone, MP3 player, or iPod®
>
> Listen without downloading on any
>   connected computer—PC or Mac, desktop
>   or laptop. Get instant music at home,
>   at work, at a friends house, at a
>   party... you get the picture.

Pricing plans:
http://www.napster.com/index.html?darwin_ttl=1290019245&darwin=s1010B&regflow_id=s1010B&naps_app_id=0

Comment: Rhapsody has a web client and a iPhone app, and the web client for Napster is pretty much the same.  Except Napster is a step worse than Rhapsody, since they don't even have a downloadable client for Windows; they have no downloadable client at all.

Comment: Mind explaining the benefit of a downloadable client and why you would want that? You don't have access to the internet?

Also, your statement:
"since so far, at least, no other "all-you-can-eat" music service has an iPhone app with downloading allowed." is incorrect.

The Napster service has an iPhone app that let's you download songs.

Your question, overall, is very confusing and I don't know quite what you are looking for. Could you explain yourself better? Are you looking for a music manager to replace iTunes? I don't see why having a desktop client is imperative.